# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php not working on server

Tags: curl, centos, composer-php

I'm on a CentOs server, trying to install composer.

When I run `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`,nothing happens. no messages, no composer.phar file. Not sure what is going on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For understanding what is going on try to make instead of:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Two separate commands:

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
```

and

```
php installer;
```

In this case you can see on which step you got the problem.